# Move values from united columns (union)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, union

[image][image]I am looking for a way to move values from united columns (union).

Using the Union command, I have merged several cleansed layers. Each source layer has the same columns (topic). Using the Union command, these columns are now numbered consecutively and stored in the attribute table.

Example:

- Layer 1: *Column a; Column b; Column c*
- Layer 2: *Column a; Column b; Column c*

After the union:

- Layer united: *Column a; Column b; Column c; Column a2; Column b2; Column c2*

I would like to have the values of the columns (*column a2; column b2; column c2*) written one below the other so that I end up with only 3 columns in the table and not 6, 9, 12, etc.

Comment: Try to [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate)

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear to me. You want to reduce the number of columns (attributes) and append these values at the bottom of the attribute table? This would mean doubling the number of features: So please elaborate an post a screenshot.

Comment: The columns of the united layers are listed numbered, as each individual layer contains the same columns. Since each layer refers to different geometries it results in NULL values.

Comment: I have added a picture, which hopefully explains what I mean